# zip loop not functioning as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, python-zip

I tried making a range based for loop using zip but it isn't selecting the entries of my list as expected.
The code is as follows:

```py
for lower, current, higher in zip(energy[:len(energy)-1], energy[1:len(energy)-1], energy[1:]):
      lowerE = round(findE(lower, current, tol),dec)
      higherE = round(findE(current, higher, tol),dec)
      print(str(lower) + " " + str(lowerE) + " " + str(current))
      print(str(current) + " " + str(higherE) + " " + str(higher))
```

where findE(min,max,tol) is an algorithm which searches zeros of numerically evalued functions between min and max with precision tol and dec is calculated from tol (currently tol is 1e-4 and dec 4).

Running the loop with start array energy = [0,0.5,2] I expect the output to be:
0 lowerE 0.5
0.5 higherE 2

where higherE and lowerE are whatever. What I'm getting instead is
0 lowerE 0.5
0.5 higherE 0.5\

what's wrong in my loop definition?

Comment: Side-note: `energy[:len(energy)-1]` is pointlessly verbose (and slightly slower to boot). Negative indices implicitly are offset from the length of the sequence being sliced, so `energy[:-1]` would achieve the same effect, and it's the encouraged form. It's extra silly, because `zip` stops when the shortest sequence is exahusted, so you didn't need to cut anything off the end at all. Your `zip` would do *exactly* the same thing written as `zip(energy, energy[1:], energy[1:])` (which might be a hint as to what is going wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop isn't zipping at three different offsets, it's just at two offsets. Eliminating the unnecessary elements of each slice (since `zip` stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted anyway), you're looping over `zip(energy, energy[1:], energy[1:])`, when you almost certainly intended to be looping over `zip(energy, energy[1:], energy[2:])` (note the change from `1` to `2` in the final slice), so you got *three* adjacent values, not one value, followed by the next value repeated twice.

Comment: yep you're right! thank you, this works! (well the findE algorithm doesn't but atleast I'm searching between the correct values)